# How to insert data into a String array in postgres stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a pseudo stored procedure as given below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data()
 RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    rec_new   RECORD;
    querystring TEXT[];

    cursor_file CURSOR FOR
        select * from tableA;
BEGIN
    --open the file cursor
    OPEN cursor_file;
        LOOP
        FETCH cursor_file into rec_new;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;    

            querystring='{insert into tableB(fileid) values %}',rec_new.fileid;

        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_file;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to create multiple insert queries with dynamic fileId's being iterated over a loop and put them in a string array `('querstring')` seperated by a comma delimiter. The code above is not giving me the exact result. What is the correct way to achieve this?

The expected output is like:

```
{insert into tableB(fileid) values ('fileA'),
 insert into tableB(fileid) values ('fileB'),
 insert into tableB(fileid) values ('fileC')}
```

Then this `querystring` array needs to be executed also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the “array append” operator `||`.

But that is an overly complicated way to solve the problem. You can do it simpler and more efficiently with something like

```
SELECT array_agg(
          format(
             'insert into tableB(fileid) values (%L)',
             fileid
          )
       ) INTO querystring
FROM tablea;
```

Comment: I need to store the queries in an array in my case the `'querystring'` variable and execute them one by one.

Comment: No problem. I have adapted my answer.

Comment: Ok, Let me put it in this way. I need only the `querystring` array like how we do in Java world by assigning values directly to the variable. Can that be achieved here? As I don't want to have the select query in my function or is this the only way around?

Comment: As I said, you can use the `||` operator to do it the way you suggested in your question. This is not the Java world, so consider using the local idiom. My query will assign directly to the variable (assignment in PL/pgSQL is just `SELECT ... INTO` under the hood.

Comment: That is working. One more ask requirement is to execute those queries in the array. How should I approach that?

Comment: Then you should do away with the array altogether and instead use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195904/discussion-between-abhilash28abhi-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: I need to aggregate all the queries first in the array and then need to execute them at the end not while inserting them. Something like a batch execute.

Comment: Then open a new question for that.